# How to save game data in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, saving-data

I'm working on a big game like clash of clans. But the problem is how I can save the data. I already know about playerprefs that is very easy way to save variable. But I want to the whole like player have created a powerplant, a farm like that type of data not in text form but in gameobject.

I already know how I can save a int, float,string variable data. I want to know to save whole data. I want to be able to save the scene (data) so that it looks the same as it was when the player left it.

Comment: Do not use `PlayerPrefs` to store game state... Read about serialization, make one yourself and use it to store that serialized data in some kind of file or even use database... just not `PlayerPrefs`

Comment: A title of `please some one help me` really is the least useful one I've seen in several months. It has been a feature of internet culture for the last 30+ years (e.g. Usenet, emails) to require people to use useful titles. There is no value in making it harder for people to help you.